# Install ImageMagick on MinGW

Tags: windows, imagemagick

When I install IM on MinGW I got this error

c:\Users\MumMum\Desktop\MagickCore\ImageMagick-6.7.7-0/magick/nt-base.c:1021: un
defined reference to `IsWow64Process'

How i solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

You do not specify your OS version. IsWow64Process ("Is this a Windows on Windows 64 bit process?") is only implemented in XP and later desktop OSes, and Windows 2008 and Windows 2003 SP1. See: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms684139%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

In a pinch, try installing the Portable version of ImageMagick: [Link](https://www.imagemagick.org/script/download.php#windows)